# Setting default terminal window font size in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, default, font-size

I'm a newcomer to gnuplot, and am wondering how to change the default font size (and possibly font type) of the window into which I input commands.

Currently when I start gnuplot the first thing I do is to click *Options*, *Choose Font...* then change the font size but this is becoming tedious.

Is there a file containing this information that gnuplot loads when it boots up that I need to change,  or is there an easier way?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With version 4.6.5, two lines below the `Choose Font` you have `Update C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\wgnuplot.ini` (or similar). Just change the font and then click on the `Update`-entry and that's it.

That creates an ini-file with e.g. the content

```
[WGNUPLOT]
TextFont=Consolas,12
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I now see it in the documentation, under `Windows` in `IV Terminal Types`. How newcomers are to know to look here I don't know... but then again what kind of newcomers rigorously look through documentation?